# ldap on debian, and ubuntu

Tags: dpkg, ldap

I am currently changing my Linux client from Ubuntu 16.04 to Debian 9.6, and I am trying to setup LDAP client authentication to debian machine.

While setup, I noticed that the following command does not exist on debian

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ldap-auth-config
```

To setup Debian LDAP, I have no clue how to configure.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I just change some words.

Comment: I don't know what *ldap-auth-config* is, but on Debian you'll want to `dpkg-reconfigure` the *nslcd* package with your LDAP details, then *libnss-ldapd* for including it into the local name service switch and finally *libpam-ldapd* to enable the PAM LDAP module (if you need that). Equivalently, edit `/etc/nslcd.conf`, `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and `/etc/pam.d/what-you-need`, for example `common-auth` for overall coverage.

Comment: @FerencWágner please post that as an answer. Comments are for asking for clarifications, answers should be posted as answers so the community can vote on them and the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: How it doesn't exist? Can you post the actual output?

Comment: @terdon Done, although I'm genuinely unsure whether this is the type of answer the OP seeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian you'll probably want to `apt install nslcd` and configure it with your LDAP details (or `dpkg-reconfigure nslcd` if already installed), then install/(re)configure *libnss-ldapd* for including the LDAP data into the name database and finally *libpam-ldapd* to enable the PAM LDAP module, if you use PAM for authorization. Equivalently, edit `/etc/nslcd.conf` (then reload *nslcd*), `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` (or some other service file if you don't need generic coverage across all PAM services).  See also `man pam-auth-update` in case the defaults don't fit you.

Once the above works, consider `apt install unscd` for better performance, but don't forget that this cache will have only delayed consistency with your LDAP database.